# Not generation of core

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *ip_range ;

int main()
{
  ip_range = (int *) malloc(1);
  ip_range[0]=2;
  ip_range[10]=2;
  ip_range[20]=2;
  ip_range[33787]=12444;
  printf("%d\n", ip_range[33787]);

}
```

I have malloc  just 1 block then why it is accessible till 33787 and generating core on 33788.

Comment: Acessing memory which is not your's is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Comment: `Allocating one block` means reserving one block of memory for the program. It does not make the rest of the memory *inaccessible*. You can still read/write other locations. You get the error when you try accessing some protected location, like some memory occupied by another process.

Comment: I have tried this block of code on several machines with different Configuration,,and It failed at 33788 only

Comment: @VikashKumar it's __undefined behaviour__, google that term.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal `You can still read/write other locations.` - that's not always correct.

Comment: I guess PC-Lint will cry

Comment: @ Fantastic Mr Fox :I am aware of array out of bound behaviour but my question is It is not showing Undefined behaviour when I tried this block of code in several machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing to memory which you do now own i.e. was not handed back by `malloc` , `calloc` or `realloc`. This results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Your program can do anything at all, including not producing any error message or core dump.

Comment: what will be the ideal behaviour? and better approach to understand this type of results

Comment: @VikashKumar _What will be the ideal behaviour?_: what do you mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: @VikashKumar There *is* no ideal behaviour. Have a look at this: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html

Comment: As I have stated In my comments, I have tried this code in various machine with different Configurations ,But failed at 33788 only. Then How we can say It is undefined Behaviour?

Comment: @VikashKumar try on some other architecture and the outcome will be different. Accessing memory that is not your's is undefined behaviour by definition. For example on my platform I get a segfault at 18000.

Comment: thanks guys for awesome discussion

Comment: @VikashKumar We can say this is UB, because the C standard says so. Have a look at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf article `J.2 Undefined Behaviour`

Answer (score 0):

It is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you are trying to access memory out of bound. C does not check memory bound.

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) :

> **undefined behavior** - there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program. Examples of **undefined behavior are memory accesses
>   outside of array bounds**, signed integer overflow, null pointer
>   dereference, modification of the same scalar more than once in an
>   expression without sequence points, access to an object through a
>   pointer of a different type, etc.

Comment: Thanks rsp for reference